# Redirect non-www to www for both http and https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to get the following 2 pages to redirect the www. version of their respective host;

```
http://website.co.uk > redirect to > http://www.website.co.uk
```

and

```
https://website.co.uk > redirect to > https://www.website.co.uk
```

I need to keep both HTTP and HTTPs working for the respective URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule to add `www` in both `http` and `https`:

```
# for Apache 2.4+ use this rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you're using older Apache version then use this rule:

```
# for Apache 2.2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: When navigating to internal pages, it redirects every page to /index.php. For example when you go to http://website.com/en/for-suppliers/supplier-solutions you get redirected to http://www.website.com/index.php and not http://www.website.com/en/for-suppliers/supplier-solutions as it should be?

Comment: If you place this redirect as first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and clear your browser cache then this problem won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use RewriteEngine rules?
The following should do the trick (apply it for both vhosts 80 and 443):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
#for 80 port: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```